# Trouble with text file extracting using substr

Tags: c++, c++11

I have the method

```
double TrainingSession::CalcCalorieBurnGross()
{
  int VO2_max = 48, seconds, H, t1, t2, t3;
  std::string text;
  std::ifstream hrdata("hrdata.txt");
  std::getline(hrdata, text);
  while(std::getline(hrdata, text))
  { // while running through each line of the text
    std::string time = text.substr(4,2);
    std::string time2= text.substr(7,2);
    std::string time3 = text.substr(0,2);
    std::string heart=text.substr(10,3);
    t2 = atoi(time.c_str());
    t1 = atoi(time2.c_str());
    t3 = atoi(time3.c_str());
    H = atoi(heart.c_str());
    Ht+=H;
    next+=cal_m;
    cal_m=((-95.7735+(0.634*Ht)+(0.404*VO2_max)+(0.394*weight)+
    (0.271*age))/4.184)*seconds/60;
    }
    seconds=t3*3600+t2*60+t1;

    return next;
    }
```

Next is supposed to return the sum of all the sums of the equation from the text for each line, the value should be around 1000 calories, but it´s 1.79499e-307

the 2 last numbers aren´t used 
I can send the text file to you if need it
Edit: the problem now is to count amounts of time of the same heartbeat and put each of those in the equation
sample of text file:

00:00:00,136,101,28.4

00:00:01,136,101,28.4

00:00:02,136,103,28.4

00:00:03,136,103,28.4

00:00:04,136,102,28.4

00:00:05,137,100,28.5

00:00:06,137,101,28.4

00:00:07,138,99,28.5

00:00:08,139,99,28.4

00:00:09,139,99,28.5

Comment: The second argument of `substr` is length, not index. For example if you want to read `time`, should be `text.substr(3,2)`.

Comment: @rafix07 the time is like this sir first 00 is hour, second is minutes and third is seconds, the 136 is heart beats per minute

Comment: What happens when you debug this piece of code?

Comment: @einpoklum it calculates, but i get a wrong value, it´s supposed to be around 900 to 1000 calories, if you mean errors there´s none otherwise it wouldn´t compile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this piece of code:

```
cal_m = some_function_of(H, VO2_max, weight, age, seconds);
cal = cal_m;
next = cal + cal_m;
cal_m = two;
```

this is equivalent to:

```
cal_m = some_function_of(H, VO2_max, weight, age, seconds);
next = 2 * cal_m;
```

So you are *discarding* the value of `next` from previous iterations; you're always keeping just one line's contribution (albeit doubled).

Comment: okay so it doesn´t keep the values from all the lines, but i don´t see how else to add all the values, what if i just use cal_m as return

Comment: @AhmadNaibi: You need to add the current line's computed contribution to the overall sum. At each iteration you need to have something like `overall_calorie_burn += line_calorie_burn;` (right now this would be `next += cal_m;`)

Comment: even when i do that the calorie value is far off from 1000 calories, so it´s about the position of the substring values, since i´m not sure if the placement is correct

Answer (score 0):

As noted by [rafix07](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49191434/trouble-with-text-file-extracting-using-substr#comment85387916_49191434), your use of `substr` is wrong, but instead of correcting it, you could rewrite the loop using a `stringstream` to extract the data from the string.

That will allow you to deal with the cases where the lengths of the substrings are different from the expected. Consider `H`, for example, if it represents the heart beats per minutes, it could be a number with 3 or 2 digits.

So you could write:

```
// ...
#include <sstream>
#include <array>
// ...
std::ifstream hrdata("hrdata.txt");
std::string text;
while( std::getline(hrdata, text) )
{
    std::array<char, 3> del;
    int t0, t1, t2, H;
    if ( text.empty() )
        continue;

    std::istringstream iss {text};
    if ( iss >> t0 >> del[0] >> t1 >> del[1] >> t2 >> del[2] >> H
         and del[0] == ':' and del[1] == ':' and del[2] == ',' )
    {
        int seconds = t1 * 60 + t2;   
        // ...                                                                                        
    }
}
```

Comment: I´m actually getting a different result now, thanks for clearing things, but it´s still missing something

Comment: @AhmadNaibi Well, if [this](http://www.shapesense.com/fitness-exercise/calculators/heart-rate-based-calorie-burn-calculator.shtml) is a valid reference, their formula *"for determination of calorie burn if VO2max is known"* ends with *"x 60 x T"* where T is *"Exercise duration time (in hours)"*, while you are calculating only per minutes. A larger sample of your real data and the expected results would be useful.